# How to use loops inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, datatable

I have a datatable which am passing to the StoredProcedure as a parameter and i want to execute a query inside a stored procedure for each row in the datatable.

```
datatable:
Value     
000011%
000012%
000013%
000014%
000015%
000016%

Query goes like this:
SELECT * FROM Test T
         INNER JOIN Sample S ON T.TestId=S.SampleID
         WHERE Title like'000011%' //This value will change for each datatbale row value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a loop here. By looking at your data, you could try `LEFT()` function.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Test T
         INNER JOIN Sample S ON T.TestId = S.SampleID
WHERE LEFT(Title, 6) IN (SELECT LEFT(Value, 6) FROM ParaTable)
```

Comment: Let me try your solution.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `CROSS JOIN`:

```
DECLARE @DT TABLE(V NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @T TABLE(Title NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @DT VALUES
('000011%'),
('000012%'),
('000013%'),
('000014%'),
('000015%'),
('000016%')

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('000011123'),
('00001112345'),
('000012123'),
('000012123678'),
('000013ABC'),
('DEF'),
('GHI')

SELECT * FROM @DT dt
CROSS JOIN @T t
WHERE t.Title LIKE dt.V
```

Output:

```
V       Title
000011% 000011123
000011% 00001112345
000012% 000012123
000012% 000012123678
000013% 000013ABC
```

Apply to your query:

```
SELECT * FROM Test T
         INNER JOIN Sample S ON T.TestId=S.SampleID
         CROSS APPLY datatable dt
         WHERE Title like dt.Value
```